# Explain this obj-c method signature to me

Tags: objective-c

```
- (NSInteger) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger) section
```

I'm pretty comfortable with obj-c, but I don't understand this method signature. Specifically why this method has all that extra stuff before the method name, and what it means. Like I get that the `-` is an instance method, and that the return type is `NSInteger`

but why is `tableView: (UITableView *) tableView` in front of the method name?

WHy do some instance methods for the UITableViewDataSource protocol have nothing infront of the name? `numberOfSectionsInTableView`is defined differently.

Can someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lets break it down into parts:

```
-
```

This means it's an instance method. The alternative is `+` which means class method.

```
(NSInteger)
```

This is the return type of the method. In this case it's `NSInteger`.

```
tableView:
```

The first component of the selector name (which is, in full, `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`). The `:` indicates that a parameter follows.

```
(UITableView *)
```

The type of the parameter.

```
tableView
```

The name of the parameter. This is largely irrelevant in the method signature (except as a hint to the reader as to the purpose), but in the implementation this is the variable that is bound to that parameter.

```
numberOfRowsInSection:
```

The next component of the selector name.

```
(NSInteger)
```

The type of the second parameter.

```
section
```

The name of the second parameter.

---

Note, the only required space in this entire line is the one between `tableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection:`. All other spaces can be elided to produce

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Though the most common format you'll find looks like this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

---

**Edit:** Looks like there's still some confusion about the latter part of the question. The `tableView:` component of the selector is there to provide the `UITableView*` instance that's asking the question. All of the methods in the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol provide the sending tableview as an argument. Some of these methods have other arguments, and some don't. The ones that have additional arguments are all formatted as `tableView:someOtherThing:` (e.g. `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`), but this isn't required. It could be called `numberOfRowsInTableView:forSection:`, or `numberOfRowsInSection:ofTableView:`, or even `foo:bar:`, but it's a stylistic choice that was made by the API developer to preserve a consistent naming scheme that assist both the developer and the person reading the code later. As for the methods that don't take any other parameters, they look like `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` because that's just a natural name for the method. They can't be called `tableView:numberOfSections` because that's an illegal selector (all components after the first *must* have a parameter associated, and therefore must have a trailing `:`).

Comment: Okay, so why is the selector name `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` rather than `numberOfRowsInSection:`

Comment: @Alan: Because it is. The full selector name contains every component of the selector. `tableView:` is different than `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`, which is different than `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, which is different than `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. While the method signature and method calling uses infix notation for parameters, which some people mistake for keyed arguments, it's really just a syntactic thing.

Comment: @Alan: When you write `[foo callMethodWithArg1:arg andArg2:arg2]` this is actually calling the method `-callMethodWithArg1:andArg2:` and passing the parameters `arg` and `arg2`.

Comment: I guess I'm asking, why did the developer choose to implement the method as: `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` instead of `numberOfRowsInSection:` It's not a class method, so why is a tableView required? Its it because protocols can't define class methods?

Comment: @Alan: Twofold. First off, this is a method declared in a protocol, and the `tableView:` component serves as a sort of informal way to "namespace" the method, so you don't conflict with some other protocol's `numberOfRowsInSection:`. Secondly, the tableView parameter is actually very important in a lot of cases. The object that's being asked this question may have multiple tableviews and will need some way to figure out which tableview is asking the question, and that's what the first argument provides.

Comment: @Alan: I also don't understand your confusion about class methods. The `tableView:` bit doesn't just say "this comes from a UITableView", it actually provides the `UITableView*` instance that sent the message as the first argument. It's wholly unrelated to class methods vs instance methods.

Comment: Gotcha! And it's not implemented as a class method because it needs to operate on instance data of the class that is implementing the protocol. The confusion was thinking that the protocol was being implemented by UITableView (which is clearly not the case).

Comment: @Alan - if it can help `protocol` in objective-C are like `interface` in java.

Comment: @VinceBurn: Interestingly, it's actually the other way around. Java interfaces were "inspired" by Obj-C protocols.

Comment: @KevinBallard yes but more person knows more about java than objective-C... well... I think... for me it's the other way around, I know more my ojbective-C than my java... but I'm not normal...

Comment: @VinceBurn: Thanks. I knew about protocols and how they are similar to interfaces in Java and C#.

Answer (score 2):

In each case a reference to the `tableView` that is asking for data or calling a delegate method is given to the user

```
//                                                         |
//                                                         V
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

//                                       |
//                                       V
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

That way if you have one `datasource`/`delegate` object that is in charge of multiple `UITableView`'s you can distinguished between which one is asking for data/ is calling a method.

This is a pretty common pattern.

If you are using a `UITableViewController` the likelihood is that you will ignore the `tableView` parameter anyway as you are normally only dealing with the one `UITableView`

The reason for the ordering of the params e.g. `tableView` being at the beginning is probably preference and it reads better when there are multiple parameters, however when you only have the `tableView` paramater is must be the last.